# How to add a button which saves the post then executes a function

Tags: theme-development, customization, wp-admin

Currently, I have a function called '**pub_notification**' in my functions.php file which sends an email when the post is published, using the following code:

```
add_action('publish_post', 'pub_notification');
```

I would like to separate these functions by adding another button called '**Send Notification**' below the default 'update/publish' button, which, when clicked, would save the post, including the custom field data, and then execuite my '**pub_notification**' function.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Of course this means I do not want to tie the execution of my '**pub_notification**' function to either '**save_post**' or '**publish_post**' actions, but rather I want it tied to the click of the '**Send Notification**' button.

Answer (score 1):

On first look it doesn't seem that there is a filter or action tied to the meta-box to allow you to do this. My bust suggestion would be to add a [custom meta-box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) that includes the Notification button, and from that click you should be able call the save post function and then call your custom notification.